# ZF2/3 Load Modules from Database

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I would like to know if there is a way to load modules from a database table in zend framework 2 preferable 3? I want to be able to dynamically disable or enable modules based on a status column inside a database table

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can accomplish this by attaching listener to some of `ModuleManager` events.
There are docs for v3 https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-modulemanager/module-manager/ and v2 https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html

And don't forget autoloading for v3

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question [tom_cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2673535/tom-cruz), I realize that I have exactly the same one ;-)

I went through the ZF2 source code of ModuleManager, ModuleManagerFactory, ModuleEvent and some listeners. After analyzing the flow, my new question is:

"What do I expect from an active/inactive module?"

Nearly every important stuff **is** done by the events [Nemutaisama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829585/nemutaisama) mentioned. i.e. loading config by adding getConfig() Method to the Module.php class.

ATM I'm not able to answer the above question. I'll come back to this one laters. But right now, I think it's an application problem, not a framework one.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this some time ago by:

1. Create a "Core" Module responsible with fetching modules from database.
   1.1 In the Module.php add module listener

   ```
   public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $manager)
   {
     $sharedEventManger = $manager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
     $sharedEventManger->attach(ModuleManager::class, ModuleEvent::EVENT_LOAD_MODULES_POST, new ModuleListener(), 10000); 
   }
   ```
2. Module Listener created by me was something like:

   ```
     public function __invoke(ModuleEvent $event)
     {
      $target = $event->getTarget(); 
      $serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

      if(! $serverName) { return; }

      //module ok 
      if(! $target instanceof ModuleManagerInterface) { return; }

      //config data
      $configListener = $event->getConfigListener(); 
      $config = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false); 

      //app modules
      $modules  = $target->getModules(); 

      //select active modules
      $adapter = new Adapter($config['db']); 
      $sql = new Sql($adapter); 
      $select = $sql->select(['c' => 'customers'])
                 ->join(['cm' => 'customers_modules'], 'cm.customer_id = c.id', ['module' => 'module'])
                 ->where(['c.domain' => $serverName])
                 ->where(['cm.active' => 1]); 

      $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
      $result    = $statement->execute();

      if($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult() && $result->getAffectedRows()) {

       //change db connection params here (if you use different db for customers)

       while ($current = $result->current()) {

           if (! in_array($current['module'], $modules)) {
               try {
                   $target->loadModule($current['module']) ;
               } catch (\RuntimeException $e) { 
                   $target->loadModule('WQ' . str_replace($current['prefix'], '', $current['module']));
               }
               $modules[] = $current['module'];

               $module = $target->getModule($current['module']);

               if (($module instanceof ConfigProviderInterface) || (is_callable([$module, 'getConfig']))) {
                   $moduleConfig = $module->getConfig();

                   $config = ArrayUtils::merge($config, $moduleConfig);
               }
           }

           $result->next(); 
       }
   }

   $target->setModules($modules);
   $configListener->setMergedConfig($config);

   }
   ```

Hope it was useful.