# How to load modules in zf2 from database

Tags: php, database, dependency-injection, module, zend-framework2

i would like to know if there's a way to have application module in zf2 that look in database and load other modules based on a table, maybe this could be a duplicate from:

[ZF2/3 Load Modules from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549601/zf2-3-load-modules-from-database)

but i dont see any up votes from answer, and i dont know if that is the better approach.

Comment: What have you tried? There are three answers to the other question that hint to solutions, just because they don't have up votes doesn't mean they're not relevant.

Comment: they approach to have a module to load other modules with module listner i dont know if im wrong, but have a listner looking for a database with a new adapter its not good approach right? What im trying to achieve is have in Application, one way to look just one time to witch module load for diferent clients, like a configurator, i tried edit module config progamatically but is not good approach either

Comment: You can listen `ModuleEvent::EVENT_LOAD_MODULES_POST` event of `ModuleManager`, then check database. IMO database connection in this situation would be overload. It'll run for each page load. It's better if you can generate these data to some kind cache file. So you can read from that file.

Comment: I do exactly that, i create in a separated config file and load in bootstrap